# Complex function question

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

The question is as follows:
Define a function $f:\mathbb C→\mathbb C$ such that $∣\{z∈\mathbb C:f(z)=0\}∣=5$ and $∣\{z∈\mathbb Q:f(z)=0\}∣=1$.

How do I go about solving something like this? I'm thinking the function in question has to be rational and complex on order to satisfy the two statements. But how the heck do I get two different moduli?

Comment: Perhaps it is a cardinality/counting function rather than a modulus/magnitude  function

Answer (score 3):

I think that $∣\{z\in\mathbb C:f(z)=0\}∣=5$ and $∣\{z\in \mathbb Q:f(z)=0\}∣=1$ mean respectively that the cardinality of the set $\{z\in\mathbb C:f(z)=0\}$ is $5$ and the cardinality of the set $\{z\in \mathbb Q:f(z)=0\}$ is $1$, that is $f$ has $5$ distinct complex zeros with exactly one of them in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree five with one root in $\mathbb{Q}$ and four distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.$ For example $f(z)=z(z^4+1)$. Are you able to find another one?

Comment: Argh drat, it's cardinality! That makes perfect sense now thank you! What a dumb mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

Take $4$ distinct irrational numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ and define$$f(z)=z(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d).$$